# How can I display an image using the "em" unit?

Tags: html, css, image, xhtml, font-size

I've created a `<div>` with `width:10em` and `height:5em`.
Now I would like to display an `<img>` (GIF image) in this `<div>` with the exact same size.
But apparently it doesn't "know" the `em` unit. It shows the picture in 10x5 *pixels* instead.

How can I display this `<img>` using the "em" unit?

Comment: What markup have you used? did you try and size it using CSS, or just with the attributes for width and height (which only take pixel dimensions)

Comment: which browser did you test it with?

Answer (score 15):

Use this code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>This is 10em x 5em</p>
    <div style="width:10em; height:5em;">
    <img style="width:10em; height:5em;" src="logo.png" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works in Firefox 3.5, Internet Explorer 8 and Opera 10.0 Beta on Windows XP.

Comment: No point in repeating the exact same width/height values. You might as well either a) Do away with the enclosing div or b) change the image's values to 100%.

Answer (score 8):

You can style img with CSS:

```
img.MyImage {
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
}

<img class="MyImage" src="image.gif" />
```