# How to set size for div when the fonts are all set in em?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page using only "em" for font size.

The page is going to have a grid (tiles) with each cell having one image with some text above and below the image. The images are all in 200px X 200px in size. The Grid Cell would be somewhat larger than the image to accommodate the text areas.

How should I go about setting the height and width of the Div and Img tag, given that I want to rely only on "em" and not "px" for font size.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're looking for or there is more to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259123/how-can-i-display-an-image-using-the-em-unit

Comment: @grmmph  I don't think I want to set img size in "em" because it will distort the image.

Comment: It wont if you set only the width attribute. It work just like you'd use it with `px` but relative to the document default font size.

Comment: I am looking at websites of a few big companies (like walmart.com), and they are all using "px" for font-size and also for div, img tags.  Do you know of any good website that is using "em"?  I am finding only blogs that talk about "em".

Comment: I'm wondering why do you need to style things that are not fonts with `em`s. I'd rather use a grid system based on percentages for `div`s and `img`s.

Comment: My page width is 1200px, and I have to display around 4-5  Grid Cells in each row. Even if I use percentage, it will have to be "something out of 1200px" (such as 20%, which is 240px per Cell).  But I am unable to determine if 240 (or 20%) will be sufficient, if somebody's "1 em" is equal to 20px.

Comment: I am not sure I really understand your problem and how using `em` will solve it. Are you concerned about images pixelated images over 200px, right? Why not just use percentages and limit the image size to 200px using `max-width`?

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to account for people who have a very large default font size on the computers. I am hoping to create a page which displays correctly for them as well. I think I need to do some experiments. I found cnn.com  is using "em" a lot. I even came across "rem"..  so I will investigate that.

Comment: The default font size is depending on the browser they are using. You can easily define your site's default font size by `html, body {font-size: 14px}`. People might have different resolutions or they might zoom in, but that will increase all the elements relatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`em` is a relative unit of measurement that inherits its value from the font size of the parent element, so to apply consistent widths to your `img` elements using `em` you'll need to define a font size somewhere in your document structure using a measurement in `px` and inherit from that.

For reference's sake, where `1em` equals `16px`, an image with a width of `200px` would be `12.5em` wide- `200 / 16`.

You'll want to specify your own measurement in `px` at least once in any case to ensure cross-browser compatibility. Not every browser uses the same default font size and it's possible that users have manually changed the default font size of their browser. If you rely on defaults, you very likely won't get consistent results, and it will be detrimental to your grid design.

Comment: Thanks but that seems counter to what "em" is meant for. As I understand it, the "em" measurement is useful for letting the Browser display the text in a size that is acceptable to the user. Some accessibility challenged people will have default computer font to be really large.

Comment: This is true, and presents an interesting design challenge. If you're still keen on sizing with `em` alone you may want to look into CSS media queries to supplement your `em` grid- they should help you target a wider variety of display options.